# word segmentation algorithm, n-gram

Tags: c++, algorithm, n-gram

I'm working with n-gram (2-gram). I have to read and segment word from file (more than 5000 file text) but my algorithm is to slow. It took me 1 hour to have done. Do you have any suggestion or something to improve it. Thanks so much. This is my code:

```
void CKhung::duyet_mot_file(string ten_file2) //work with a file
 {
string tien_to = "H:\\\\Visual Studio 2010\\\\Projects\\\\Bai_tap_lon_bai_1\\\\Bai_tap_lon_bai_1\\\\TechCrunch_Files\\\\";
string ten_file = tien_to + ten_file2;   //this is file name
char str[100];
string temp;
string buffer;
string temp1;
int i;
long key;
int sp;  //space
CTu n_gram;       
CDs_noi_don ds_tu;  //list 2-gram of a file
fstream file;
file.open(ten_file);
for (int j = 0; j <3; j++)    /* get through 3 first line*/
    getline(file,temp1,'\n');
while (getline(file,temp,'.'))
{
    sp = -1;
    i = 0;
    if (temp.length() == 0) continue;
    /*Duyet tung cau sau tien xu ly*/
    while (temp.length() != 0)
    {
        while (temp[0] == ' ')
        {
            temp.erase(0,1);
            if (temp.length() ==0) break;
        }
        if (temp.length() == 0) break;
        while (!((temp[0] >='0' && temp[0]<='9')||
            (temp[0] >= 'A' && temp[0] <= 'Z')||
            (temp[0] >= 'a' && temp[0] <= 'z')))
        {
            temp.erase(0,1);
            sp = -1;
            if (temp.length() == 0) break;
        }
        int k;
        if ((k = temp.length()) == 0) break;
        i = 0;
        while ( i < k && ((temp[i] >='0' && temp[i]<='9')||
            (temp[i] >= 'A' && temp[i] <= 'Z')||
            (temp[i] >= 'a' && temp[i] <= 'z')))
        {
            i++;
        }
        temp.copy(str,i,0);
        str[i] = '\0';
        string tu(str);
        temp.erase(0,i);
        if (sp <= 0)
        {
            buffer = tu;
            sp = tu.length();
        }
        else
        {
            buffer = buffer + " " + tu;
            n_gram.set_tu(buffer);
            key = bang_tu->them_phan_tu(n_gram);  //add 2-gram to a hash table
            if (key == -1) continue;
            ds_tu.them_node(key);
            buffer.erase(0,sp+1);
            sp = buffer.length();
        }
    }
}
/*==========================================================*/
/*Sau xong mot van ban, cap nhat so van ban Xuat hien va bang cap tu*/
for (int j = 0; j < ds_tu.get_so_pt(); j++)
    bang_tu->tang_so_vb_xh(ds_tu.truy_xuat_node(j));
/*========================================================================*/
/*Cap nhat bang cac file lien quan*/
CThong_tin_file tt_file(ten_file2,ds_tu); //khi thoat chcon thi ttfile bi giai phong
dsach_file.them_file_vao_bang(tt_file);
}
```

Comment: Your code is hard to follow, please add "executive summary" of the algorithm - or a short readable pseudo code that describes it without diving into C++ technicals

Comment: For starters, I would avoid *consuming* from the input string, just find the location of the first and last character of each word and copy that out to the buffer. There is no need to go through the work of removing the characters in the input string.

Comment: @amit `Read a sentence of file to temp. while (temp.length>0) {if (temp[0] == ' ') delete temp[0]; if (temp[0] is a special character) { delete it; delete buffer}; read a word from temp to tu; delete it in temp; if(sp<0(buffer is empty)){add tu to buffer; set sp = buffer.length()} else{add tu to buffer; add buffer (n-gram) to hash table; add buffer to list n-gram of file; delete first word of buffer; set sp = buffer.length()} }` Do it until EOF. Sorry because of my bad English. :( Thanks

Comment: @DavidRodríguez-dribeas Is there any way to know the first and last characters of word without go through it?

Comment: @RuồiTrâu: I think he meant something more in the lines of: *read one line of input, remove spaces and special caracters from the beginning, locate the end of the word and copy to `tu`, removing it from the input string...* That is a more descriptive than procedural. BTW, you will have issues with inputs like `"^ #"`... you need to skip/cleanup all characters you want at the same time. Currently after removing a special character you don't verify whether the next character may be a space.

Comment: @RuồiTrâu: The first character, according to your definition, is the first character in the set `[0-9A-Za-z]`, you can just move a cursor until you hit it. You can then use a second character to move forward until you find a character that is not in the set. Now you know the first and last characters by index. You can then start again from the first position after the word you just found. No operation modified the input buffer at all, no moving characters around, no need to allocate memory in other strings...

Comment: @DavidRodríguez-dribeas Thank you. I understood. But do you think it's enough? Because it take a too long time now. :(.

Comment: I don't know what you really need to know, I don't know what your inputs are. I don't know if that will be *enough*, but it is clearly a good start, you are doing *a lot* of unneeded operations. After you cleanup the basics, if it is still slow you should profile and figure out where the time is being spent.